# Ajax AutoComplete for jQuery "onEmpty"-type of event

Tags: autocomplete, datatables, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm using Ajax Autocomplete for Jquery (https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/) with DataTables to search on a specific column.

Using `onSearchComplete` and `onSelect` from Autocomplete I can filter both the input and the table together as the user is typing (`onSearchComplete`) and when they select an entry (`onSelect`):

```
$("#scoreboard_site_name_filter").autocomplete({
    serviceUrl: "/wiki/extensions/CFBHA/models/_mSiteNames.php",
    onSearchComplete: function(suggestion) {
        update_scoreboard_by_site_name_filter(suggestion);
    },
    onSelect: function(suggestion) {
        update_scoreboard_by_site_name_filter(suggestion);
    }
});

function update_scoreboard_by_site_name_filter(suggestion) {
    var colname = "site_name:name";
    if (scoreboard.column(colname).search() !== suggestion) {
        scoreboard.column(colname).search(suggestion).draw();
    }
};
```

However, when the input is deleted, then the DataTable is left filtered on the last input because neither event is fired in that case.

I've tried the `keyup` and `change` events on the input itself to pass an empty string to the DataTable search:

```
$("#scoreboard_site_name_filter").on("keyup change", function() {
    var suggestion = "";
    update_scoreboard_by_site_name_filter(suggestion);
});
```

If I place it before the autocomplete then it has no affect and if I place it after then of course I lose the ability to filter the table as I type because it fires after the autocomplete.

How can I detect when the input has been deleted and then re-filter the table on an empty string (i.e., clear that filter)?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I was overthinking it . . .

I removed the `onSearchComplete` event and just went with the `input` event on the input itself and everything is working great.

I left the `onSelect` for the Autocomplete and am now properly passing `suggestion.value` instead of `suggestion`.

Here's the proper code for anyone interested:

```
$("#scoreboard_site_name_filter").on("keyup change", function() {
    update_scoreboard_by_site_name_filter(this.value);
});
$("#scoreboard_site_name_filter").autocomplete({
    serviceUrl: "/wiki/extensions/CFBHA/models/_mSiteNames.php",
    onSelect: function(suggestion) {
        update_scoreboard_by_site_name_filter(suggestion.value);
    }
});

function update_scoreboard_by_site_name_filter(suggestion) {
    var colname = "site_name:name";
    if (scoreboard.column(colname).search() !== suggestion) {
        scoreboard.column(colname).search(suggestion).draw();
    }
};
```

Additionally I updated the code to make the search regex if the suggestion is actually selected (clicked on or entered on) and to add a class to the input as an indicator that the table is now filtered on that exact search term:

```
$("#scoreboard_site_name_filter").on("input", function() {
    update_scoreboard_by_site_name_filter(this.value, false);
});
$("#scoreboard_site_name_filter").autocomplete({
    serviceUrl: "/wiki/extensions/CFBHA/models/_mSiteNames.php",
    onSelect: function(suggestion) {
        update_scoreboard_by_site_name_filter(suggestion.value, true);
    }
});

function update_scoreboard_by_site_name_filter(suggestion, selected) {
    var colname = "site_name:name";
    if (!selected) {
        scoreboard.column(colname).search(suggestion).draw();
        $("#scoreboard_site_name_filter").removeClass("autocomplete-input-selected");
    } else {
        scoreboard.column(colname).search("^" + suggestion + "$", true, false).draw();
        $("#scoreboard_site_name_filter").addClass("autocomplete-input-selected");
    };
};
```